# Simple SVG Grid not being shown in IE 10 and IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, svg

I got this little SVG grid

```
<svg id="grid-svg" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="smallGrid" width="10" height="10" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M 10 0 L 0 0 0 10" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.7" />
    </pattern>
    <pattern id="grid" width="100" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#smallGrid)" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="-100%" y="-100%" width="200%" height="200%" fill="url(#grid)" />
</svg>
```

I got it in a template html. Because I don't want it to remain in the main page for a reason.
Then I just clone that piece of SVG, create a wrapper div, and append the grid-svg to it.
Then I apply the grid dynamically with jQuery.

It works for Chrome and Firefox, but it doesn't work for IE 10 and IE 11.

Do you know why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the SVG using D3.js and i had the same issue.
I wrote the below code to resolve the issue

```
    $('#lineChartSVG g').remove();
    $('#lineChartSVG path').remove();
```

here i am removing the previous g and path, replacing with the new one.

Keep your  tags in the static content and then call the above code where you used your code. This should work

Answer (score 0):

This was solved already, i was doing a jquery clone() to get it from the template, which is wrong. Now it works fine.

Comment: Hi @msqar, I am also facing the same Issue. I am Using .html() method to append defs to svg, it is working fine in all browsers except IE 9+. Can you please help me out ??

$('#lineChartSVG').html('<defs><linearGradient id="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="1"><stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--top" offset="0%" /><stop class="lineChart--gradientBackgroundArea--bottom" offset="100%" /></linearGradient></defs>');